# How to get same color when plotting numpy image array for same pixel value multiple times

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to work on some pixel manipulation on a sequence of images. I encountered an issue when plotting same value of pixel having different color when plotted with different range of pixels.

For example, I have an image with six different pixel values(0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6):

Code #1 :

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

image = np.zeros(shape=[256, 256], dtype=np.uint8)

cv2.circle(image, center=(50, 50), radius=10, color=(2, 2), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(100, 100), radius=10, color=(3, 3), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(150, 150), radius=10, color=(4, 4), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(75, 200), radius=10, color=(5, 5), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(200, 89), radius=10, color=(6, 6), thickness= -1)


plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: image 1]

Now when I add two more shapes in the image with different pixel value(7, 12), then color for all the existing pixels changes

Code #2 :

```py
image = np.zeros(shape=[256, 256], dtype=np.uint8)

cv2.circle(image, center=(50, 50), radius=10, color=(2, 2), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(100, 100), radius=10, color=(3, 3), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(150, 150), radius=10, color=(4, 4), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(75, 200), radius=10, color=(5, 5), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(200, 89), radius=10, color=(6, 6), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(21, 230), radius=5, color=(7, 7), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(149, 250), radius=5, color=(12, 12), thickness= -1)


plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

How can I ensure same value of pixel gives me same color irrespective of any other pixel present or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the colormap used. Matplotlib adapts colormap to the plotted values.
If you want to make sure it is the same colormap values/range that is being used, please specify the range explicitly using max and min values:

```py
# Here adapt and choose the values that suits you the best
min_value = -10
max_value = 10

image = np.zeros(shape=[256, 256], dtype=np.uint8)

cv2.circle(image, center=(50, 50), radius=10, color=(2, 2), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(100, 100), radius=10, color=(3, 3), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(150, 150), radius=10, color=(4, 4), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(75, 200), radius=10, color=(5, 5), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(200, 89), radius=10, color=(6, 6), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(21, 230), radius=5, color=(7, 7), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(149, 250), radius=5, color=(12, 12), thickness= -1)

plt.imshow(image)
plt.clim(min_value,max_value) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Perfect, now with the colormap range set, it works well. Thanks